# Outlook 2013 POP Account Reprompting for Password with Roaming Profile

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, outlook, password, microsoft-office-2013, roaming

I'm attempting to setup POP accounts on Outlook 2013 for roaming profile users in an RDSH pool. I have policies setup for folder redirection on the Documents folder and a policy for default PST location (among others).  I'm currently experiencing an issue with the password prompt reappearing when a user opens Outlook on another server in the RDSH pool.  All other settings are carried over including the pst.

I have setup a login and logoff script to copy the Local AppData in the Roaming AppData so it's picked up with the Roaming Profile.  However, the issue still persists.  I also tried using [WhatChanged](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php) to track where the password is being stored (user registry or profile folder) but found nothing.

A little insight into where the 'Save password in your password list' checkbox stores the goods.

Thanks!

Comment: KB2965270 installed ? Fixed problem: "When you log on to a computer in a domain that contains roaming profiles, you are still prompted for passwords in Outlook 2013. This issue occurs because the persistence of the saved account credential is Local Machine but not Enterprise."

Comment: I wish it was, I checked a few of the servers involved and didn't find KB2965270.  However, I did neglect to link one of the forum articles I tried to implement: [Office 2013 not saving credentials..](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/289058)

Comment: please install it :)

Comment: Due to past update issues, I assumed the KB 'broke' the functionality  ;)  Anyway, I downloaded the update manually and attempted to install it; however, the installer indicates it's already installed.